# Sorting an array does not update the Dom

Tags: ember.js

I can not make the following code work in my test app:

```
this.propertyWillChange('tableContent');
this.get('tableContent').sort(function (a, b) {
     var nameA = a.artikel_name,
     nameB = b.artikel_name;
     if (nameA < nameB) {
        return -1;
     }
     if (nameA > nameB) {
        return 1;
      }
      return 0 //default return value (no sorting)
  });
 this.propertyDidChange('tableContent');
```

The data gets sorted, but the dom is not updated.

The template looks like this:

```
<tbody>
    {{#each NewApp.router.gridController.tableContent}}
        {{#view NewApp.TableRow rowBinding="this"}}
            <td style="width: 100px">{{view.row.product_no}}</td>
            <td align="right" style="width: 100px">{{view.row.price}}</td>
            <td>{{view.row.artikel_name}}</td>
        {{/view}}
    {{/each}}
</tbody>
```

I tried to reproduce this problem with a short jsfiddle snippet. But there it works. The only difference is, that I fetch the data using an ajax call (and some additional router setup).

```
selectionChanged: function () {
   var that = this;
   if (this.selection) {
    $.getJSON("api/v1/lists/" + this.selection.id + "/prices", function (content) {
        that.set('tableContent', content);
    });
}
}.observes('selection')
```

The same code works if i copy the array and reassign the copied array.

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle? It's possible to simulate an AJAX call, so this case should be possible to demonstrate in a fiddle ...

Comment: [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rogergl/PY7Hr/22/) - But I have no public available data to simulate the ajax call.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to use the built-in SortableMixin ? If not, is this good for you ?

JavaScript:

```
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.activities = Ember.ArrayController.create({
  content: [{name: 'sleeping'}, {name: 'eating pizza'},
            {name: 'programming'}, {name: 'looking at lolcats'}],
  sortProperties: ['name']
});

App.ActivityView = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "li",
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("{{content}}")
});

App.SortButton = Ember.View.extend({
  tagName: "button",
  template: Ember.Handlebars.compile("Sort"),
  click: function() {
    App.activities.toggleProperty('sortAscending');
  }
});
```

jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/Sly7/cd24n/#base

Comment: @MilkyWayJoe yep, but I will wait for rogergl to see if it works for his app :)

Comment: I don't know if this will work for his particular implementation since he's using a property to watch the changes in the collection, but that property is being changed to the same value 'newOrder' the button is clicked so it fires the `sort` method in the controller, but it never gets re-set, so it seems to me the `sort` method fires only once since the next time it changes the value of that property it will be the same value it had previously. Am I wrong? I think he should use your implementation, seems much cleaner and does the job

Comment: Problem solved. #each NewApp.router.gridController.tableContent does not work and #each NewApp.router.gridController.content but #each NewApp.router.gridController does work.

Comment: Since the last comment was not complete: Problem solved. #each NewApp.router.gridController.tableContent does not work and #each NewApp.router.gridController.content does not work but #each NewApp.router.gridController does work. @MilkyWayJoe I used .notifyPropertyChange to make the sort method repeatedly work. But toggleProperty is indeed much cleaner.

Comment: And did you use the `sortProperties` property ? In other words did you try using the built-in sorting stuff in ArrayController instead of your's ?